# Specify CSS content property with elm-css

Tags: elm

Using [elm-css](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/), I would like to specify the content property in a before pseudo-element

I translated

```css
div.boxclose{
    float:right;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-right:-30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #605F61;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 11px 3px;       
}

.boxclose:before {
    content: "×";
}
```

with

```
    div
        [ css
            [ float right
            , marginTop (px -30)
            , marginRight (px -30)
            , cursor pointer
            , color white
            , border3 (px 1) solid darkGrey2
            , borderRadius (px 30)
            , backgroundColor lightGrey
            , fontSize (px 31)
            , fontWeight bold
            , display inlineBlock
            , lineHeight (px 0)
            , padding2 (px 11) (px 3)
            , before [ content "×" ]
            ]
        ]
        []
```

but it produces an error message : The `content` value is not a function, but it was given 1 argument.

I did not find the right function for "content".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `property` function of *elm-css* like this:

`css [ before [ property "content" "'x'" ]]`

*Side note:*
The `content` function is used for the `flex-basis` property. See more in the specs.
https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/latest/Css#content